Can anybody help me identify IC 1Q0__?
Can anybody help me identify this burnt IC (the markings are partially obstructed):



This is a Rohm BM1Q00XFJ device. It's a AC/DC converter.

Picture found in its datasheet, which can be found here.
The way I found it was by searching "SOP-8 1Q0" on Google and it brought me to Rohm's website. Whether it's ...01FJ or ...02FJ is difficult to say.

1 or 2 operational amplifiers opa344 opa345 in same chip, see specs
https://www.ti.com/product/OPA344
TI mentions there's a new version of this OPA named TLV9001.
or
2 MOSFETs in same chip, AO4392
check
https://www.datasheet4u.com/datasheet-pdf/Alpha&OmegaSemiconductors/AO4932/pdf.php?id=674641

got it, thanks, looking for a TI page with working link

Thanks for the edit. I don't think it's the OPA344 because that's a SOT23-6 device and the AO4392 device would likely have their company logo on the chip (I've seen a lot of these chips from that particular supplier).

There are manufacturers that copy chips and print a partial of the reference on chips. But yes, I also agree, I just spent a few minutes browsing datasheets online. It could be something else. It's right next to 2 big rectifying diodes and the trafo. It cannot fall too far anyway.

I voted your answer.
